# Specifying child class (or any class) as return type when Invoke method

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns

Based on my classes below, how should I setup `Apply` method so that when I call it, I can specify what `BaseResult` return type that I want?

The purpose is to have the invoking code to know what child class (implementation of `BaseResult`) that Apply is returning (again, considering that calling Apply from `IRequest`, not the the implementation of it)

The conditions are:

- There could be many implementations of `IRequest`
- There could be many implementations of `BaseResult`

**Code**:

```
void Main()
{
    // For example purpose, let's pretend 'myreq' is retrieved from reflection. So, there's no way I would know it's type of MyRequest. And there will be many other implementations of IRequest.
    var req = new MyRequest();

    var request = (IRequest)req;

    // How should I setup Apply method so that when I call the method, I can specify what BaseResult return type that I want?
    // In this example, I would like Apply method to return Result type, which inherits from BaseResult.
    var res = req.Apply<Result>();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public interface IRequest
{
    string GetValue();
    T Apply<T>() where T : BaseResult;
}

public class MyRequest : IRequest
{
    // How should I setup Apply method to allow returning any BaseResult I want? Each IRequest implementation of Apply method may return different BaseResult type.
    public T Apply<T>() where T : BaseResult
    {
        // Doesn't work here
        // Can't implicitly convert type BaseResult to T
        return (BaseResult) new Result();
    }

    public string GetValue() { return string.Empty; }
}

public class Result : BaseResult
{
    public string Message { get; set;}
}

public class AnotherResult : BaseResult
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class BaseResult
{
}
```

Comment: Can you constrain the type of `Apply<T>` to require a `new()`?

Comment: Your code is not generic. What if you called `Apply<AnotherResult>`? You would be casting a `Result` to `AnotherResult` which would fail at runtime,

Comment: @DStanley, that's why I am here in SO, to seek other people thoughts and solutions to my problem.. :)

Comment: @stack247 But you're explicitly creating a `Result` in the method.  Should it be creating a `T` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Apply method, cast new instance as T.

```
public T Apply<T>() where T : BaseResult
{
    var newInstance = new Result();
    return newInstance as T;
}
```

Comment: This would fail at run-time if `T` were `AnotherResult`.

Comment: @Enigmativity `T` in my call is not `AnotherResult`. Even if it's, operator `as` will not fail at run-time. If returned object is not the type of `T`, it will just return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you constrain the type of `Apply<T>` to have a default constructor?

```
public T Apply<T>() where T : BaseResult, new()
{
    //you could put settable properties on BaseResult
    //(or similar interface) and set them here, as well.
    return new T();
}
```

This would also require you to specify the constraint on the interface:

```
public interface IRequest
{
    string GetValue();
    T Apply<T>() where T : BaseResult, new();
}
```

Comment: The solution you proposed is returning new `T`. If I have object type of `BaseResult`, how should I return that object and not the new `T`?

Answer (score 0):

You can change return type of `Apply<T>` to `BaseResult`.

```
public interface IRequest
{
    string GetValue();
    BaseResult Apply<T>() where T : BaseResult;
}

public class MyRequest : IRequest
{
    public BaseResult Apply<T>() where T : BaseResult
    {
        return new Result();
    }

    public string GetValue() { return string.Empty; }
}
```

Edit: Figured that you would need to make a type cast anyway with this solution, but in the calling code instead. So it doesn't really solve the problem.

Edit 2: Actually, it seems like returning generic type serves this particular purpose - to avoid casting in calling code. Is it really necessary, given that required type is known in the code calling `Apply`?

Comment: This is an odd signature - `public BaseResult Apply<T>() where T : BaseResult` - the `T` isn't doing anything useful here.

Comment: Well, I guess it still constrains callers from "requesting" some type not derived from `BaseResult`. Though I agree that it's a weird application of generics.

Comment: @DmitryRotay Yes, my purpose is to have the invoking code to know what child class (implementation of `BaseResult`) that `Apply` is returning (again, considering that calling `Apply` from `IRequest`, not the the implementation of it).

Comment: @DmitryRotay From your solution, I could also do `public BaseResult Apply()`. The calling code then have to use reflection to see what type of `BaseResult` that the specific implementation of `IRequest` is returning. Then, use that information to cast returning object. What do you think?

Comment: @stack247 I think it won't work. `IRequest` returns `BaseResult`. You don't know what concrete type it returns until you call `Apply<T>` method. In fact, my point was that current signature assumes that you already know which type you want it to return (you pass it as a type parameter) so all these shenanigans with generics make little sense. I guess you should elaborate a little on what you're trying to achieve. Maybe there's a better way to do it.